# The stool is under the ladder. You want to remove the stool. Would you say "to take the stool out of/off the ladder"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

A child put a ladder on a stool to get into a play house (see the picture in the link) because the ladder is not tall enough.

The stool is not **on** or **in** but **under** the ladder.

You want to remove the stool.

Would you say "**to take the stool out of/off the ladder**"?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd say I'd take the stool *out from under* the ladder.

[Here](https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/nioshtic-2/20028062.html) is an example sentence which is a slightly different situation, but still:

> The victim was non-responsive, so the farmer pulled him out *from under the ladder* and called to two workers in the farm yard.

Comment: I would say 'take it out from under the ladder'. Including the 'out' is more idiomatic to my ears (native English speaker from UK.)

Comment: @Jelila yeah, it sounds better with *out*, I agree.

Comment: I'd just say 'take the ladder off the stool'.

Answer (score 1):

In most common verbal usage, you'd chain some prepositions together:

Spoken American English:
"Take the stool out from under the ladder."

Comment: Why "out"? The stool is not inside anything?, What about "Take the stool away from under the ladder."?

Comment: See Glorfindel's answer as well - uses the "out" expression too. It may be an American thing.

Comment: It's _in_ the space between the ladder and the floor.

Comment: In UK English, including the 'out' is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

As the stool is *under the ladder*, I would say:

> **to take the stool from beneath the ladder**